# Odd Excel Search

Tags: excel, return-value

I'm stumped.  I need excel to look at the value in M2 and find an exact match in column K.  When it finds an exact Match in colomn K, I need it to copy the contents of the cell 3 to the right of the column K's match location.

I can get the value of the cell just to the right of M2, but I need it 3 right of the match on column K

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,6)
```

I tried a script that did nothing

```
Sub FindMatch()

'Declare variables
Dim cellValue As String
Dim cellAddress As String

'Get the value in cell M2
cellValue = Cells(2, 2).Value

'Find the cell address of the first exact match for cellValue in column M
cellAddress = Application.Match(cellValue, Range("M:M"), 0)

'If there is a match, put the cell address in cell H2
If cellAddress <> 0 Then
Cells(2, 3).Value = cellAddress
End If

End Sub
```

I had an idea to put the cell reference in the cell and then try to copy the contents 6 cells to the right of the match

This did what I wanted and put the cell address of the match into the cell I have highligted

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(M2,K:K,0),14)
```

However, I can't get it to copy the value of the cell, 5 columns to the right of the match.

```
=Cells(H2).offset(0,6).value
```

Any ideas?

```
=IF(Cells(2, 2).Value <> "", Cells(2, 2).Offset(0, 6).Value, "")

=Cells(H2).Offset(0, 6).Value
```

```
Sub CopyCell()

'Declare variables
Dim cellValue As String
Dim cellAddress As String

'Get the value in cell H2
cellValue = Cells(2, 2).Value

'Get the cell address of the cell 6 columns to the right of H2
cellAddress = Cells(2, 2).Offset(0, 6).Address

'Copy the cell value to the new cell
Cells(cellAddress).Value = cellValue

End Sub
```

```
=IF(MATCH(M2, K:K, 0) <> 0, ROW(MATCH(M2, K:K, 0)), "") & "," & COLUMN(MATCH(M2, K:K, 0))
```

Comment: Have you tried `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX`+`MATCH` or `XLOOKUP` yet?

Comment: `=vlookup(m2, K:N, 3, False)` should do the job, no?